# Deserializing Web Api parameter fails in case of large json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web API service that has an `HTTP Post` method that contains a `byte[]` parameter which fails to get deserialized when larger JSON ( ~30MB) is sent as body content, thus having `null` value. For smaller JSON it's been able to deserialize properly into the `byte[]` array.

Basically what I am trying to do is send a `byte[]` to Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web API endpoint that will upload this payload as blob storage in Azure. Below is the code for API and the calling code.

Note here `payload` parameter is having null value:

```
public class MyBlobController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("UploadPayload/{containerName}/{blobName}")]
    public async Task<string> UploadPayload([FromBody] byte[] payload,
        string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        //code for uploading blob
    }
}
```

Calling code for this endpoint:

```
var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payloadData); //payload is large byte array

HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsondata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//Instantiating the HttpClient. 
{
    var HttpClientInstance = new HttpClient();

    HttpClientInstance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    HttpClientInstance.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("nl-NL"));
    HttpClientInstance.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

}
HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = null;

//Sending a post request to the Blob Api.
apiResponse = await HttpClientInstance
    .PostAsync("http://localhost:8999/api/MyBlob/UploadPayload/mycontainer/myblob", content);
```

I have also gone through this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267) that tells how to change the maximum limit size of `HTTP Post` request. I have also enabled that setting such that it is able to accept large request but still no luck with deserialization.

Comment: What is the exception you get? Post it here.

Comment: i am getting no exception just that my byte array is null. Earlier i was getting  response as Payload Too Large Http Status code  413 but after increasing the request limit size i am not getting any exception just that my byte array is always null